# Many to Many relationship using ListProperty Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, listproperty

I'm building a facebook app which needs access to facebook page of user.The Scenario is like this:-

A User(Admin) can have multiple Pages and One Page have multiple Admins. And each Page can have multiple posts on it.I have seen google app engine documentation (Modelling Entities Relationships).They used ListProperty for many to many relationship and reference property for One to Many relationship.

Structure of classes as I think is like

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    profile_url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    access_token = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    pages = db.ListProperty(db.Key)


class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    page_access_token = db.TextProperty()
    users = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Post(db.Model):
    page = db.ReferenceProperty(User,collection_name='posts')
    post_content = db.TextProperty()
    published = db.BooleanProperty()
```

Is this right or I do need to change in it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's different ways of doing many-to-many relationships.  Using ListProperties is one way.  The limitation to keep in mind if using ListProperties is that there's a limit to the number of indexes per entity, and a limit to the total entity size.  This means that there's a limit to the number of entities in the list (depending on whether you hit the index count or entity size first).  See the bottom of this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview

If you believe the number of references will work within this limit, this is a good way to go.  Considering that you're not going to have thousands of admins for a Page, this is probably the right way.

The other way is to have an intermediate entity that has reference properties to both sides of your many-to-many.  This method will let you scale much higher, but because of all the extra entity writes and reads, this is much more expensive.